# Setting exact number of iterations for Logistic regression in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm creating a model to perform Logistic regression on a dataset using Python. This is my code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
my_classifier2=linear_model.LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',max_iter=10000)
```

Now, according to [Sklearn doc page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), max_iter is maximum number of iterations taken for the solvers to converge. How do I specifically state that I need 'N' number of iterations ?

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: By replacing `max_iter=VALUE` with whatever value you want?

Comment: @AMC is `max_iter` the number of iterations the algorithm will do ? or is it the **maximum** number of iterations it will do ?

Comment: @deltascience, `max_iter` is the max number of iteration of the chosen `solver` used by `LogisticRegression`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m not sure, but, Do you want to know the optimal number of iterations for your model?  If so, you are better off utilizing `GridSearchCV` that scan tune hyper parameter like `max_iter`.
Briefly,

1. Split your data into two groups: train/test data with `train_test_split` or `KFold` that can be imported from sklean
2. Set your parameter, for instance `para=[{‘max_iter’:[1,10,100,100]}]`
3. Instance, for example `clf=GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression, param_grid=para, cv=5, scoring=‘r2’)`
4. Implement with using train data like this: `clf.fit(x_train, y_train)`

You can also fetch the best number of iterations with `RandomizedSearchCV` or `BayesianOptimization`.

Answer (score 1):

About the `GridSearchCV` of the `max_iter` parameter, the fitted `LogisticRegression` models have and attribute `n_iter_` so you can discover the exact `max_iter` needed for a given sample size and regarding features:

```
n_iter_: ndarray of shape (n_classes,) or (1, )

Actual number of iterations for all classes. If binary or multinomial, it
returns only 1 element. For liblinear solver, only the maximum number of
iteration across all classes is given.
```

Scanning very short intervals, like 1 by 1, is a waste of resources that could be used for more important `LogisticRegression` fit parameters such as the combination of `solver` itself, its regularization `penalty` and the *inverse of the regularization strength* `C` which contributes for a faster convergence within a given `max_iter`.

Setting a very high `max_iter` could be also a waste of resources if you haven't previously did a minimal feature preprocessing, at least, feature scaling or maybe imputation, outlier clipping and a dimensionality reduction (e.g. PCA).

Things can become worse: a tunned `max_iter` could be ok for a given sample size but not for a bigger sample size, for instance, if you are developing a cross-validated learning curve, which by the way is imperative for optimal machine learning.

It becomes even worse if you increase a sample size in a pipeline that generates feature vectors such as n-grams (NLP): more rows will generate more (sparse) features for the `LogisticRegression` classification.

I think it's important to observe if different solvers converges or not on  given sample size, generated features and `max_iter`.

Methods that help a faster convergence which eventually won't demand increasing `max_iter` are:

- Feature scaling
- Dimensionality Reduction (e.g. PCA) of scaled features

There's a nice sklearn example demonstrating the [importance of feature scaling](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_scaling_importance.html#importance-of-feature-scaling)